# How to remove unwanted lines in Axis scale of a graph when using D3.js?

Tags: backbone.js, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have Logarthmic values in my Graph using D3.js. But here I have more number of lines which I don't need actually. how can I remove it. Please find the attached screenshot for reference..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the values you want to see strictly using tickvalues:

```
var s = d3.scale.log().domain([1, 100]).range([300, 0])

var axis = d3.svg.axis();

axis.scale(s).tickFormat(
    function (d) {
        return s.tickFormat(3,d3.format(",d"))(d)
}).tickValues([1,10,100])

d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)")
        .call(axis);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2hvxc/2/